Postgresql select by array of substrings
I have the following db schema
Product



Id
Name
ManufactureId




Guid (PK)
string
(FK)


-
ECOSYS M2640idw
3


-
Infoprint 1140
2



Manufacture



Id
Name




(PK)
string


1
Hitachi


2
IBM


3
Kyocera Mita




Both names (product and manufacturer) can consist of several words;

I have a search string (provided by user from mobile app) compiled in a random order ( product name manufacture name or manufacture name product name) names could be partial, I need to select db entries that will match with user input, there is no delimiters in search strings between manufacture  and product parts.
eg

search input: Kyoce ecos should provide in results an entry ECOSYS M2640idw
search input: kyocera mi ecosys should provide in results an entry ECOSYS M2640idw
search input: ibm should provide results Infoprint 1140

Could you please help to find a better way to construct SQL query to approach this on Postgresql
Thanks, for any help

What have you tried to do? If user input is 'IBM' should your query output contain 'Infoprint 1140'? In source data example show links between Product and Manufacture.

yes for 'IBM' the result should be Infoprint 1140, filtering performs by 'Name' fields

If input is 'kyocera and you have 2 or more product for this manufacturer, query should output all products for 'kyocera?

@ValNik yes, correct

Solution:
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW product_search AS
SELECT
    p.id AS product_id,
    p.name AS product_name,
    m.name AS manufacture_name,
    to_tsvector('english', p.name || ' ' || m.name) AS search
FROM
    product p
LEFT JOIN
    manufacture m ON p.manufactureid = m.id;

-- Index the tsvector column
CREATE INDEX product_search_idx ON product_search USING gin(search);

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html
Query:
SELECT product_id, product_name, vendor_name
FROM product_search
WHERE search @@ to_tsquery('english', :bind_query_here);

Fulltext:
:bind_query_here = "+word1 +word2" --must contain
:bind_query_here = "word1 word2"  --can contain
:bind_query_here = "-word1 -word2" --cant contain
:bind_query_here = "word1 | word2" --1or2 contain

https://neon.tech/postgresql/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-full-text-search

Thanks for idea to improve perfomance with separate VIEW, I think I will consider that option on next iteration

JOIN Product and Manufacturer and string_to table(search input).
Then use LIKE or ILIKE for search words and word parts.
You need to decide whether you will

search by whole words or by part of a word
case sensitive or ignore case

For search whole words solution example provided by @Mertuarez.
I suggest example for search parts of words.
select *
from Product p
left join Manufacture m on p.ManufactureId=m.Id
inner join string_to_table('kyo',' ') ws 
   on   p.name ilike concat('%',ws,'%') 
     or m.name ilike concat('%',ws,'%') 




id
name
manufactureid
id
name
ws




100
ECOSYS M2640idw
3
3
Kyocera Mita
kyo



For search input 'kyo print' output  is



id
name
manufactureid
id
name
ws




100
ECOSYS M2640idw
3
3
Kyocera Mita
kyo


200
Infoprint 1140
2
2
IBM
print



fiddle

great thanks for suggestions, we also can use :* pattern for searching partially
